# Xcode выдает ошибку (C++)

Tags: c++, xcode

malloc: *** error for object 0x1005ae750: pointer being freed was not allocated

Создал класс string, реализовал операцию присваивания, и когда начинаю тестировать , то ругается компилятор, и показывает на деструктор.
Помогите, буду благодарен

```
#include "String.h"
String :: String (const char *str) {
    size = sizeof(str) +1;
    string = new char [size];
    strcpy (string, str);
    string [size] = '\0';
}

String :: String (const String &ob) {
    size = sizeof(ob.string) +1;
    string = new char [size];
    strcpy (string, ob.string);
    string[size] = '\0';
}

String :: ~String () {
    delete [] string;
}

void String :: show () {
    cout << string << endl;
}

String String :: operator = (const String &ob) {
    String temp;
    temp.string = new char [ob.size + 1];
    strcpy (temp.string, ob.string);
    temp.string [ob.size + 1] = '\0';
    return temp;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out , const String &ob) {
    out << ob.string;
    return out;

}
istream& operator >> (istream& in, const String &ob) {
    String temp;
    temp.string = ob.string;
    in >> temp.string;
    return in;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(str)` делает не то, что вы думаете. Он возвращает размер указателя в байтах (всегда 4 или 8).

Comment: А как тогда узнать размер строчки входящей?

Comment: [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen).

Comment: Я поменял строку sizeof на strlen, и ошибка все равно возникает. Плюсом ко всему выдается такое предупреждение: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int'

Comment: Значит у вас где-то еще ошибки. В копирующем конструкторе не забыли заменить? Предупреждение говорит, что длина строки теоретически может не влезть в `int` (по хорошему нужно использовать `size_t`, который у вас равен `unsigned long`).

Comment: `string [size] = '\0';` в паре мест записывает за границу массива. Он вообще не нужен, `strcpy` сама пишет нулевой байт. Еще, `.size` хранит длину строки вместе с нулевым байтом или нет? Похоже что с, но тогда в `temp.string = new char [ob.size + 1];` `+1` - лишний.

Comment: Я кажется понял в чем ошибка, но не знаю как ее поправить. Я в main написал ~ 
const char *str = "Ka";
    delete [] str;
    cout << str;
    return 0; ~
И выдает ту же самую ошибку, почему он не хочет удалять str?

Comment: Это другое. `delete` может удалить только то, что создано `new`.

Comment: Как тогда освободить память от str?

Comment: Сам `str` удаляется автоматически при выходе из функции. Строка, на которую он указывает (`"Ka"`) существует все время работы программы, ее не нужно освобождать.

Comment: Спасибо большое!